# Page not responsive while new serviceworker is installing. All static files fetched again with every small update

Tags: javascript, service-worker

1. Our page becomes non-responsive while a new serviceworker is installing. Our goal is to install the new serviceworker, but to prevent the install handler to request resources that fight for bandwith with the main page's requests.
2. The serviceworker install event takes a large amount of time, because all the files are being fetched again, even after a tiny update. The serviceworker should only (re)fetch the dynamic files after an update (see mutableRequests in the code below). And just the NEW static files should be fetched after a serviceworker update, not all the static files (see immutableRequests in the code below).

Please find below comments in the code which explain the things I have tried already.

```
// Register the serviceworker:

  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
   window.addEventListener('load', function() {
     navigator.serviceWorker
            .register('/sw.js')
            .then(function() { console.log("Service Worker Registered"); });
   });
  }
```

```
// The serviceworker:

'use strict';

// To update the version of the serviceworker:
var CACHE_NAME = 'swwo-cache-v143';

// The 'static' assets:
var immutableRequests = [

    // Many assets here:
    '/js/awesomplete.js',
    '/js/bootstrap.min.js',
    '/img/earth-from-space.jpg'
    // ETC...

];

// The 'dynamic' assets:
var mutableRequests = [

        // Only a few assets here:          
        '/index.html',
        '/legal.html'
        // ETC...       

];

// Here the goal was to make sure that all the mutableRequests are being fetched again, and only the NEW immutableRequests:
self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(CACHE_NAME).then(function(cache) {
      var newImmutableRequests = [];
      return Promise.all(
        immutableRequests.map(function(url) {
          return caches.match(url).then(function(response) {
            if (response) {
              return cache.put(url, response);
            } else {
              newImmutableRequests.push(url);
              return Promise.resolve();
            }
          });
        })
      ).then(function() {
        return cache.addAll(newImmutableRequests.concat(mutableRequests));
      });
    })
  );
});


self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  var requestURL = new URL(event.request.url);

// Try the cache first:
  if (requestURL.origin == location.origin && requestURL.pathname == '/') {
    event.respondWith(caches.match('/index.html'));
    return;
  }

// Analytics exception:
  else if (requestURL.host === 'www.google-analytics.com') {
  event.respondWith(fetch(event.request));
}

 else {

 event.respondWith(
// Try the cache:
    caches.match(event.request)
// Fall back to the network:
      .then(response => response || fetch(event.request))
// A general fallback:
      .catch(function() {   
       return caches.match('/offline/index.html');

      })
  );}

});


// Removing the old cache:
self.addEventListener('activate', function(event) {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.keys().then(function(cacheNames) {
      return Promise.all(
        cacheNames.map(function(cacheName) {
          if (CACHE_NAME !== cacheName) {
    console.log('Deleting out of date cache:', cacheName);
            return caches.delete(cacheName);
          }
        })
      );
    })
  );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1.

```
          return caches.match(url).then(function(response) {
```

There's a bug: you should call cache.match to match against the cache you're interested in. Not cacheS with an "s" :)

2.

If you're always updating the name of the cache

```
// To update the version of the serviceworker:
var CACHE_NAME = 'swwo-cache-v143';
```

then none of the previously fetched and cached assets are going to be found from there, right?

Remember: the browser considers a SW script new if even SINGLE BYTE changes in the SW script file, thus any change in the assets you want to cache will make the SW new to the browser. You don't need to keep a separate version number anywhere if you don't need it for anything. Here it seems to cause a problem. You can put the version number in a comment if you want to have it.

One thing to note, too: if you don't really need the SW to register/update ASAP, you could delay it. Use setTimeout to delay SW registration for 15 seconds or whatever so that the user gets to use the page as soon as possible. This makes the app smoother.

Comment: Thank you pate. About the bug, I guess the approach is to look in all the caches, like described here: https://github.com/w3c/ServiceWorker/issues/891

Comment: About updating the name of the cache, and removing the previous cache. It seems to me that this happens with the activation of the serviceworker. The install event fires before that.
I would say that this would mean that during the install event the previous cache is still available. What do you think?

Comment: About using setTimeout that could take away some of the pain. At the same time, I guess then the same issue will arise after 15 seconds? The install event is at the moment really blocking everything (e.g. simply clicking an internal link gives no result, until after the serviceworker is completely installed).
What would be ideal I think, is to fire the install event right away, but to deprioritize it, so that the main page's requests get priority. Would something like that be possible?